# How to make a button add a word after the original text

Tags: c#, winforms

How to make a button to add a word after the original text? Let's say the textbox's text is: "5" , how can i make it's result: "5 People" after clicking a button? (in C# - Windows Form Application)
P.S I've looked for tutorials and i didn't find any, anything you give me would be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [`+=` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/sa7629ew.aspx)

```
textBox1.Text += " People"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text += " People";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to the Text of the TextBox in the button's click event:

```
txtBox.Text += " people";
```

Be aware that this adds the text to the content whether it makes sense or not. I'd suggest to either validate the contents first or put a separate label next to the TextBox if "people" is meant as a "unit". The latter has a lot of advantages, i.e. that you do not have to worry about the "people" text when parsing the value of the TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this. `String Concatination` and by using `StringBuilder`.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text += " People"; // Concatination
}
```

**Alternate**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    str.Append(textBox.Text);
    str.Append(" People");
    textBox1.Text = str.ToString(); 
}
```